# On click load iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, footer, scripts, iframe

I have this html

```
<a href="#1647278006925-e8321147-313b" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">LISTEN</span></a>
```

that is printed in my page and opens an accordion with an iframe in it.
The iframe:

`<iframe id="myiFrame" class="stop-lazy" data-src="https://some.iframe" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%;min-height: 150px;"></iframe>`

I am trying to create a jquery code that will load the iframe only when the user click on the link.
So i have tried to set the below script in the footer.php:

`<script> $(".vc_tta-title-text").click(function(){ var iframe = $("#myiFrame"); iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));  }); </script>` 
but it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

(Note:It would be better to trigger the click event from the href="#1647278006925-e8321147-313b" )

*I can not edit the html.

**I can edit, add or remove classes or ids in the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you inspect your code for any errors?

If the error is "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function", then maybe you can add the code as below.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //your code starts here
    <iframe id="myiFrame" class="stop-lazy" data-src="https://some.iframe" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%;min-height: 150px;"></iframe>
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you @BlackWoods for your help . this was the problem.